# Cannot find vlc_vlc.desktop

Tags: vlc, snap, .desktop

I had installed VLC at some point, and then uninstalled it. But for some reason the icon still appears in my applications list.

[image]

I've looked for the .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/` and `/.local/share/applications` and `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` but I don't see anything named VLC. I also did a search for .desktop files and don't see anything VLC related. Out of ideas for places to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo find / -xdev -iname '*vlc*.desktop'
```

Installed via snap then:

```
sudo snap remove --purge vlc
```

via apt:

```
sudo apt purge vlc
```

You may be seeing the available apps from "Software" store.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!!